# python2.7 - Grouping CSV data by hour of day

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I need to group day by hour from the data formatted as below:

```
Hour of Day,Users,Sessions,Total Events
2016010100,12,12,550
2016010101,12,12,296
2016010102,9,7,289
2016010200,11,11,191
2016010201,5,5,61
2016010202,11,11,214
2016010300,15,15,746
2016010301,6,6,256
2016010302,9,9,933
2016010400,12,12,589
2016010401,5,5,278
2016010402,2,2,63
```

(Hour 00 represents midnight through 1 AM)

I need to find a python code that will help me group the data into hours so that I can do statistics summary. The output should be a total of 24 csv files (1 file for each hour).

An example of the desired output for Hour 00:

```
Hour of Day, Users, Sessions, Total Event
2016010100,12,12,550
2016010200,11,11,191
2016010300,15,15,746
2016010400,12,12,589
```

Since the file contains more than 14000 lines, how can I do this for all hours?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read your file as a list and split each line using comma then group by using list comprehension if first element ends with your hour format:

```
read_file=open("input_file.txt")
text=read_file.readlines()
for i in range(24):
    hour_format="{:>02d}".format(i)
    output_list = ([line for line in text[1:] if (line.split(",")[0]).endswith(hour_format)])
    print ("{0}{1}{0}".format("#"*30, hour_format))
    print (text[0])
    for line in output_list:
        print (line.strip())
```